# How to inspect element for Selenium v3.6 as FireBug is not an option any more for FF 56?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, webdriver, firebug

I am trying to find a way to use FireBug for FF. Unfortunately it's not supported for `selenium v3.6`. What can be done if I have to locate the elements, will "Inspect" element will be sufficient?

If I get down to less version of selenium, will that help?

Answer (score 4):

If you visit the *GitHub Page* of [FirePath](https://github.com/pierretholence/firepath), it clearly mentions that :

> FirePath is a Firebug extension that adds a development tool to edit, inspect and generate XPath expressions and CSS3 Selectors

Now if you visit the *Home Page* of [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/), it clearly mentions that :

> The Firebug extension isn't being developed or maintained any longer. We invite you to use the Firefox DevTools instead, which ship with Firebug next.

So the direction is clear that, we have to use *Development Tools* which comes integrated with the Mozilla Firefox 56.x + release onwards.

---

### Example Usage :

Now, let us assume we have to identify the **xpath** or **cssSelector** of the *Search Box* on *Google Home Page* `https://www.google.com/`.

1. Open *Mozilla Firefox* or *Google Chrome* browser and browse to the url `https://www.google.co.in`
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open the *Developer Tools*
3. Within the *Developer Tools* console, with in the *Elements* tab, once you click on the *Inspector* and *mouse hover* the *Search Box* and the *WebElement* pertaining to the *Search Box* gets highlighted within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

[image: inspector]

4. Within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) you can *right click* and on *mouse hover* over `Copy` item you can clck on either of the following sub menu item:

   - `Copy selector`: To copy the *CssSelector* (absolute)
   - `Copy XPath`: To copy the *XPath* (absolute)
5. Snapshot:

[image: copy_xpath_selector]

---

### Additional Steps

Referring the copied *CssSelector* or *XPath* you can also construct a logical unique *XPath* or a *CssSelector*.

---

### Testing your own XPath

To test your own written *XPath*, within the *Developer Tools* console, click on  the `Console` tab and within the editor paste the logical unique **xpath** you have constructed in the following format and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>:

```
$x("//*[@name='q']")
```

Example:

[image: XPath]

---

### Testing your own CssSelector

To test your own written *CssSelector*, within the *Developer Tools* console, click on  the `Console` tab and within the editor paste the logical unique **cssSelector** you have constructed in the following format and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>:

```
$$("[name='q']")
```

Example:

[image: CssSelector]

Answer (score 0):

Inspect element is sufficient if you only want to inspect element. 
I found `Firepath` helpful with testing the locators. Downgrading to `Firefox 30 – 54` should be enough. It has nothing to do with Selenium version.

Also you can look at [Chropath](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en) for Chrome

Comment: Thank you all for wonderful suggestions.Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this step in your case and check.

1. Open A Blank Tab in Firefox
2. Type about:config in address bar then press enter (click on I accept the risk!)
3. Find browser.tabs.remote.autostart
4. Select the option then click the mouse right side
5. Turn The Option As False
6. Close the browser for restart browser
7. Open browser again, inspect the element. I hope It Works Properly.

Answer (score 0):

ChroPath extension for xpath and best replacement for FirePath. It has no dependency on other extension like firepath was dependent on firebug. Just add ChroPath to Chrome browser and use it.

Download link- [ChroPath](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo)

Features-

1. gives unique xpath and css selectors
2. It opens as sidebar tab in devtools panel where you can access DOM, inspect element in left side and write the XPath/CSS in right side.
3. verify xpath and css selectors
4. gives the list of matched node
5. highlight the web element on hover
6. scroll the hidden element in view area on hover.
7. ChroPath is the only extension which gives unique CSS selectors for selected or inspected element.