# How to find xpath without firepath into firefox version 57.0

Tags: selenium, xpath, ui-automation, selenium-ide, firepath

Facing difficulty to find xpath without firepath in new Firefox version 57.0.

In the new Firefox version, firepath is not supported.

Can anyone please suggest a new way for using xpath?

Comment: The best way is [to create your own](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

Comment: Check this QA [**`How to inspect element in selenium3.6 as firebug is not an option any more for FF 56?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-in-selenium3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-for-f/46702281#46702281)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Firefox, but I like to use Google Chrome for this. Press F12, this opens the developer tools. Then click anywhere in the HTML structure and press Ctrl + F or Cmd + F if you're on a Mac.

In the search bar that appears you can search by XPath, Css selectors or strings. So if you type `//div/div/form` for example, you can immediately check if the XPath works.

You can also right click on an element and choose copy > xpath

Answer (score 2):

you can try [ChroPath](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo) which is the best replacement of firepath.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Right click on the web page and click on Inspect Element or Ctrl+Shift+Q
[How to inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apU8r.png)

Step 2: Click on inspector [Inspector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPceF.png)

Step 3: Verify in console

Comment: Your ans is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution for a 64 bit Windows OS: Install 46.0.1 firefox 32 bit version on your system. You can use this lower version of browser for debugging xpaths using add-ons.