# Xpath eval on latest version of firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, xpath

I was using Firepath to evaluate my custom Xpath. I understand that Firebug and Firepath no longer work on latest versions of Firefox. Now you have to use Developer Tools and copy and paste XPath to the console.

How can I evaluate my custom XPath in Firefox Developer Tools?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: To evaluate an XPath, run `$x("custom xpath")` in the console (F12).

Comment: Thank you i will try that should i expect a message or will it highlight the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to inspect element in selenium3.6 as firebug is not an option any more for FF 56?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-in-selenium3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-for-f/46702281#46702281)

Answer (score 0):

Use [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate), for example:

```
document.evaluate('//td[contains(@class, "owner")]//div[@class="user-details"]/a', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML
```

If you run it on this page, it will show your username. Running it on some other page, that does not have similar element, would show error:

> TypeError: document.evaluate(...).singleNodeValue is null

More generically, `document.evaluate` returns an object of type [XPathResult](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XPathResult), which can be used to retrieved various aspects of evaluated XPath. You can also customize result type (4th argument).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firefox menu -> web developer -> web console
Then at the bottom of the console there is place to type command, type

First allow pasting in console.

```
$x("allow pasting")
```

Then, use your xpath

```
$x("Your xpath here")
```

[image: mouse hover on start icon will highlight the element in the webpage]