# Do we have any alternative for firepath in firefox quantum browser?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, firebug

Do we have any alternative for fire-path in firefox quantum browser? Firepath is used to identify the xpath. But I could not see any useful plugin like that in firefox quantum browser.Please let us know if there is any alternative for firepath in firefox quantum version

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-in-selenium3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-for-f/46702281#46702281

Comment: Are you trying to _**get**_ the xpath, or _**test**_ the xpath? The answers so far are how to test xpath you already have. But the question sounds more like you're trying to have a tool that gives you the correct xpath.

Comment: yes..i'm looking for a tool or plugin that should create the xpath automatically when we inspect the element

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem with the built-in tools? (I ask jokingly)

I know that at least Chrome and Firefox both allow you to right-click on the source code and choosing to copy the xpath:

**Chrome**:

While viewing source code, right click on the element you wish, and choose `Copy > Copy XPath`

**FireFox**:

Right click on the element in the page and choose `Inspect Element`. While viewing the source, right click the element again and choose `Copy > XPath`

Now, both of these methods copy the most sloppy method of XPath:

`/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/text()[1]`

While it will work, it is the most brittle way to do things. You are better off learning how to write the code by hand and then use a tool to validate it's getting what you're looking for.

Also remember that both the copy and the verification are time/context sensitive. In other words, the path could change because you're interacting with the screen (select options close, modals disappear, timers keep running, etc). But once you learn, that is a tool you can use forever.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using Chrome, my advise would be to use the dev tools of chrome. Hit F12 (or right click on an element and inspect it) in chrome, go to the console tab and typ your xpath like:

```
$x("xpath here")
```

Comment: Chrome's poor 'Developer tools' UI reminds people the days of Firebug and Firepath. Fact if anyone was/will use firefox, only if they can again give support of Firebug, no matter its quantum or phantom :P

Comment: Im not okay with using chrome!

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking for instant xpath finder similar to Firepath in that case the below link will help you find the Xpath which is a chrome extension.[Ranorex Selocity](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ranorex-selocity/ocgghcnnjekfpbmafindjmijdpopafoe?hl=en)