# How to find XPATH and CSS in Mozilla firefox v58.0.1 ? Not able to find any Firebug etc

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-firefoxdriver

How can I find *XPath* and *CSS* in Mozilla Firefox 58.0.1?

I can't find Firebug.

I tried adding the add-ons but it does not allow me to do so.

I'm using Selenium 3.8.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to inspect element in selenium3.6 as firebug is not an option any more for FF 56?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-in-selenium3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-for-f)

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click the element you want to inspect
2. Select *Inspect element*
3. Right-click in the now open Developer Tools on the element you want the XPath of
4. Select *Copy* -> *XPath*

On the right hand side you can also inspect all CSS properties of the element.