# How to prevent automatic HTML source code fixing on web browser

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

My original html source is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> aaaaa<bbbbb </title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see there is a mistake in the title. There is an unclosed `<` between `aaaaa` and `bbbbb`.

When I open this page with web browsers (firefox, chrome and edge), the browsers fix the problem and change the source code to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> aaaaa&lt;bbbbb </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

So is there a way to prevent browsers to fix problems in original htmls? When I browse, I want to see original html source.

Note: I am using firefox geckodriver with python/selenium. So any solution that includes a configuration in firefox or python code would be OK.

Comment: I'm using chrome.  Both "view source" and inspector shows source as is on my end.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fundamental difference between the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) shown through *View Source* i.e. using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and the markup shown through [Inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700764/how-to-inspect-element-for-selenium-v3-6-as-firebug-is-not-an-option-any-more-fo/46702281#46702281) i.e. using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Both the methods are two different browser features which allows users to look at the HTML of the webpage. However, the main difference is the **View Source** shows the HTML that was delivered from the web server (application server) to the browser. Where as, **Inspect element** is a *Developer Tool* e.g. [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) to look at the state of the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) after the browser has applied its error correction and after any Javascript have manipulated the DOM. Some of those activities may include:

- HTML error correction by the browser
- HTML normalization by the browser
- DOM manipulation by Javascript

In short, using **View Source** you will observe the *Javascript* but not the *HTML*. The HTML errors may get corrected in the **Inspect Elements** tool. As an example:

- With in *View Source* you may observe:

  ```
  <h1>The title</h2>
  ```
- Whereas through *Inspect Element* that would have corrected as:

  ```
  <h1>The title</h1>
  ```

---

### This usecase

Based on the above mentioned concept the following markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> aaaaa<bbbbb </title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

gets corrected as:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> aaaaa&lt;bbbbb </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```