# Python Selenium: Unable to find xpath to click on element within iframe

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm using this code but the can't get it to work with the xpath:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
browser.get("https://planetradio.co.uk/cool-fm")
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]/div[4]/button[2]').click()
```

Comment: Which element are you trying to click?

Comment: A button pops up with the text "accept all" to agree to the cookies, I had hoped the above xpath would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element <kbd>ACCEPT ALL</kbd> is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://planetradio.co.uk/cool-fm/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='ACCEPT ALL']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://planetradio.co.uk/cool-fm/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='SP Consent Message']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='ACCEPT ALL']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: planetradio]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. How did you know the xpath of the button was //button[@title='ACCEPT ALL'] rather than the //*[@id="notice"]/div[4]/button[2]

Comment: @Pythonaccount See this [detailed discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702281/7429447).