# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//b[text()='35']"}

Tags: python, function, selenium, try-except, nosuchelementexception

Why is my exception not kicking in and catching the error. I know it cant go up to 35 because there is no 35, but it should peform my exception if this is the case or not? Thanks for answares in advance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
website = "https://langerball.de/"
driver.get(website)

land = "DEUTSCHLAND"
x = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//a[(text()='%s')])" %land)
x.click()


def maxspieltag(): 
    i = 1
    while i in range(100):
        xpath_t = ("//b[text()='%s']" %i)
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_t)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            i -= 1
            break
        i +=1
    return i

print(maxspieltag())
```

I added a picture because it worked before now it does not want to and for better explenation:

[image]

Comment: Does `find_element` actually fire an exception?  Or does it just return `None`?

Comment: It should work because the function goes up to 35, like you can see in the titel.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Maybe i dint understand it right. find_element does not return non. I think when it gets to 35 it fires an eception. The titel is what stands under find_element.

Comment: If you run this from a command line, do you see an exception, or does it run normally?  I'm wondering if your IDE is showing you the exception when it happens, but the `except` clause is about to catch it.  That is, your debugger is fooling you.

Comment: If I run this from cmd I getthis error : line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

Comment: I thing the debugger is fooling me because first it worked fine, how do I fix this I am using Visula Studio Code.

Comment: You just tell it to continue.  F5, probably.

Comment: Yes it prints 34, how can I fix it, so that it does not showe me this error

Comment: Thank you for your time I found the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) using [*Chrome Development Tool*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702281/7429447):

[image: bundesliga]

You will observe,

```
<b>34</b>
```

is the last element within the table and the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
//b[text()='35']
```

doesn't identifies any element within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). Hence you see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to untick the option Raised Exceptions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion you might have not saved the file before executing.

I've executed your code and it's working for me.

EDIT:

Retried the entire code without making any changes before hand and here is the full error:

```
root@92fa00e3f091:/opt/code# python seleniumtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/seleniumtest.py", line 27, in maxspieltag
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_t)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//b[text()='35']"}
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/seleniumtest.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(maxspieltag())
  File "/opt/code/seleniumtest.py", line 29, in maxspieltag
    letzter_spieltag
NameError: name 'letzter_spieltag' is not defined
```

If you look at the bottom of the exception you'll find the real exception you are looking for, uninitialized "letzter_spieltag" variable. Commenting it out and retrying works:

```
root@92fa00e3f091:/opt/code# python seleniumtest.py
34
```

Here is fixed code:

```py
def maxspieltag():
    i = 1
    while i in range(100):
        xpath_t = ("//b[text()='%s']" %i)
        try:
            driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_t)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            # letzter_spieltag
            i -= 1
            break
        i +=1
    return i

print(maxspieltag())
```

Comment: Yes I should have delete letzter_spieltag becaus i change the code, I saved it and it shows me an error, I will now add a picture, can you look over it?

Comment: Could you print the exception module? Replace `except NoSuchElementException:` with `except Exception as ex:` and print the exception path with `print(type(ex))`

Comment: No cant print it, but sometimes the consol shows me the result of 34.