# Where is right-click menu in Chrome v99?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, webdriver

Tried to find xPath of an element in the latest Chrome (v99).  It looks like the right-click menu in Chrome's "inspect" pane is not available.  How does one find the xPath of elements for Selenium automation?

Comment: Copy-pasting XPaths out of your browser is a really excellent way to write flaky tests...

Comment: Well you should write your own xpath, however you'd still need inspect feature so that you can write XPath more effectively/robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome's ***Inspect*** menu item is still available after the right-click.

[image: Chrome_Inspect]

However, [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) latest version is ***Version 100.x*** which you need to upgrade to.

[image: Chrome100]

Having said that, some websites may disable the right-click for security or some other reasons. In those cases you have use the [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) to identify the desired elements.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to inspect element for Selenium v3.6 as FireBug is not an option any more for FF 56?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702281/7429447)